# In Applescript how do I enter text in a window that is not the front window?

Tags: applescript

I am new to applescript and experimenting with it. I am using a code similar to this to enter text into textedit.

```
tell application "textedit"
    activate
    set n to a random number between 1 and 100
    repeat 100 times
        tell application "System Events"
            delay 4
            keystroke n
            delay 3
        end tell
     end repeat
end tell
```

This works fine as long as textedit is in the front window, but if I do something in Chrome it will input the text into whatever text field is active in Chrome. How do I make it input the text even if textedit is in the background?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Keystrokes are always issued to the frontmost application. So if you want the keystrokes to always go to TextEdit then you must activate TextEdit before issuing the keystrokes. That's just how it works. You can't issue keystrokes to a background app.

Answer (score 1):

System Events keystroke is not the best way of doing it.

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set newDoc to make new document with properties {text:("Begin Count" & return)}
    repeat with i from 1 to 100
        set text of newDoc to newDoc's text & i & linefeed
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell
```